# How can I deploy aave protocol locally or in testnet

Tags: testnets, aave

Aave v2 mumbai testnet faucet is broken, So I was thinking to deploy the aave protocol locally or in any testnet to mint new tokens.

Aave protocol is built on hardhat and I am new on hardhat. can't find the proper command how to deploy it locally or in testnet. Really appreciate your help. Thanks!